# FindShortestTour shows erratic behaviour wrt 2nd argument

Tags: programming

`FindShortestTour` behaves erratically.
It should return a `{distance, ordering}` pair, and it does this for most values of its second argument.
But for two cases shown below, it returns an empty list. 
There is no mention of this possibility in the Mathematica documentation. 
There is no apparent reason for this behaviour. 
There are no errors or messages thrown during execution.

```
places = {{-0.16799965940098155`, 
0.24175153562415813`}, {-0.2486071472529178`, 
0.20618977684683304`}, {-0.14076440088637684`, \
-0.24171243009574903`}, {-0.6251900796628861`, -0.9717675903858705`}, \
{-0.17963581832506564`, -0.5233794053664629`}, {0.266014045257439`, \
-0.2574537949317151`}, {0.43866600854230675`, -0.3502551214679294`}, \
{0.8152887752208928`, -0.152895668542801`}, {0.0849331507331597`, \
-0.09587917268794487`}};

Array[FindShortestTour[places,#,9]&,8]
```

If you copy and paste and execute this code,
you will see that the 3rd and 6th entries are empty.
Why?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to submit a bug report with this example to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but you can work around it by changing the distance function from its default. For instance:

```
Array[FindShortestTour[places, #, 9, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance] &, 8]
```

returns answers for all the cases. There seems to be something special about your "places", since if you choose the locations randomly, it seems to mostly work fine:

```
places = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {9, 2}];
Array[FindShortestTour[places, #, 9] &, 8]
```

Comment: Yes, it mostly works fine. And yes there is probably something special about the places. I had a previous problem with FindShortestTour that was fixed just by scaling the data (!!) However, we have no knowledge on how to prefilter the data or anticipate a problem. So far, it has been a matter of running until it creates a problem, and then twiddling something and trying again.